# GWT client recieving null representation during Restlet call

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, restlet

I have 2 projects, one GWT/GAE and one GAE. Both implement the appropriate Restlet jar.

The server one return the expected JSON representation when I call it from my junit test cases (using the Java SE restlet client) or when I call it from the browser but when I call it from my GWT app it doesn't work. The call looks like this:

```
     itemSuggestProxy.getClientResource().setReference(WebSrvcConnectionMethods.getItemSuggestionURL() + queryString.trim());

     try{
         itemSuggestProxy.suggestByString(new Result<Representation>(){
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) { 

            }
            public void onSuccess(Representation rep) {
                   ....
            }
```

The Representation rep gets returned as null and when I debug both on the server the server method suggestByString() is never hit (it is if I use the browser)

I keep them on the same server (both on localhost [different ports thou]) shouldn't that get around the Same-Origin issue? It's driving me nuts that it's not throwing any kind of exception it's just returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using different ports you do have problems with the same origin policy (because same origin policy applies to the port as well as the host)

Comment: Oh, well that's a pain. I guess I'll have to combine them into one project. Thanks!

Comment: you can also use a proxyservlet in your gwt project to redirect the requests, for a good example take a look here: http://ars-codia.raphaelbauer.com/2011/02/proxy-servlet-for-gwt-environment.html

Comment: Interesting, so would I have to add Jetty and Maven to my project?

Comment: I'm struggling a little here. So the goal is to build a servlet in the server package which calls the outside server and then have the GWT client call that servlet via the standard RPC?

Comment: exactly, this way you get around the same origin policy. The browser only sees one server on the same port and one url is just a proxy to the other app